# Want to find port number from httpconf file and display it via echo command .cat httpd.conf | grep -oE "Listen'[0-9]{1,4}'"

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Want to find port number from `httpconf` file and display it via echo command, this is what I am thinking but it needs to be edited further:

```
cat httpd.conf | grep -oE "Listen'[0-9]{1,4}'" > echo "The port number for http is $arg{2}"
```

Need to search for the line `Listen 80` or `Listen <nmbr>` and grab that number to display by echo command.
Could someone help here.

Answer (score 0):

Why the need for `cat`? Try something like that:

```
grep -i 'listen [0-9]' httpd.conf | awk '{print $2}'
```

---

Tested with example file `httpd.conf`:

> test test test 
>   Listen 80 xyz
>   test test test

Output:

`80`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ awk '/Listen/ {print "The port number for http is " $NF}' /etc/apache2/ports.conf
The port number for http is 80
The port number for http is 8080
The port number for http is 443
The port number for http is 443
```